# C# - Input string was not in a correct format (Set-UserPhoto)

Tags: c#, system.io.file

```cs
public static bool SetUserPhoto(OnboardingEmployee employee)
{
    employee.IsSuccess = false;
    string filePath = "([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes(\"C:\\" + employee.Lønnummer.ToString() + ".jpg\"))";

    using (Runspace runspace = GetExchangeOnlineRunspace())
    {
        Pipeline pl = runspace.CreatePipeline();
        Command cmd = new Command("Set-UserPhoto");
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new CommandParameter("-Identity", employee.UserPrincipalName));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new CommandParameter("-PictureData", filePath));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new CommandParameter("-Confirm", false));
        pl.Commands.Add(cmd);
        List<PSObject> psoList = new List<PSObject>(pl.Invoke());
        employee.IsSuccess = ResolvePipelineErrors(pl, "Exchange.SetUserPhoto");
        runspace.Close();
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
{"Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'PictureData'.  Cannot convert value \"([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes(\"C:\\729.jpg\"))\" to type \"System.Byte[]\". Error: \"Cannot convert value \"([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes(\"C:\\729.jpg\"))\" to type \"System.Byte\". Error: \"Input string was not in a correct format.\"\""}
```

I even tried to write the string "729" at line 5 instead of employee.Lønnummer.ToString() which is also 729.

Looking forward to your respones.

Kind regards

Jakob

Comment: because its expecting `byte[]` but your are passing string

Comment: I think according to your question it should be `byte[] byteArr = File.ReadAllBytes("C:\\" + employee.Lønnummer.ToString() + ".jpg");`

Comment: Are you trying to pass the physical path to the command intead the actual bytes of the image? Not sure what api that is (Runspace, Pipeline) but it likely needs a byte[] value instead of a path.